# Split day at the time of day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whether there is any function to break up the day in the morning, day, night, evening.

Start time of morning, evening, day, night.

**like:**

```
DateTime.now.midnight.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z")    
#=> "2013-09-07 00:00:00 +04:00"

DateTime.now.morning.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z")
#=> "2013-09-07 06:00:00 +04:00"

DateTime.now.day.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z")
#=> "2013-09-07 13:00:00 +04:00"

DateTime.now.evening.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z")
#=> "2013-09-07 18:00:00 +04:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) gem is what you need. It does what you specify here and much more.

For example:

```
Chronic.parse("today morning")
Chronic.parse("today evening")
Chronic.parse("31st December 2013 morning")
```